# Mysql Joining four tables

Tags: mysql

I've been having trouble linking these tables together:

Table 1: Matches

| ID | Name | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Adam vs Lance | 2021-09-2021 |
| 2 | Bex vs Adam vs Erica | 2021-08-2021 |
| 3 | Craig vs Bree | 2021-07-2021 |
| 4 | Danielle vs Alan | 2021-06-2021 |
| 5 | Erica vs Zoe vs AJ | 2021-05-2021 |
| 6 | Bree vs Erica | 2021-04-2021 |
| 7 | Bree vs Lance | 2021-03-2021 |
| 8 | Bree vs Lance vs Zoe | 2021-02-2021 |

Table 2: Winners:

| ID | Name | Match ID | IDNum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Adam | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | Bex | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | Danielle | 4 | 7 |
| 4 | Zoe | 5 | 9 |
| 5 | Erica | 6 | 4 |
| 6 | Bree | 7 | 5 |
| 7 | Bree | 8 | 5 |

Table 3: Losers:

| ID | Name | Match ID | IDNum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Lance | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | Adam | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | Erica | 2 | 4 |
| 4 | Alan | 4 | 8 |
| 5 | AJ | 5 | 10 |
| 6 | Erica | 5 | 4 |
| 7 | Bree | 6 | 5 |
| 8 | Lance | 7 | 2 |
| 9 | Lance | 8 | 2 |
| 10 | Zoe | 8 | 9 |

Table 3: Draws:

| ID | Name | Match ID | IDNum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Craig | 3 | 6 |
| 2 | Bree | 3 | 5 |

Table 4: Players

| ID | Name | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Adam | M |
| 2 | Lance | M |
| 3 | Bex | F |
| 4 | Erica | F |
| 5 | Bree | F |
| 6 | Craig | M |
| 7 | Danielle | F |
| 8 | Alan | M |
| 9 | Zoe | F |
| 10 | AJ | F |

The query I've been trying is to look up all matches with Bree in them and order them by date.

Table 5: Output:

| Match ID |
| --- |
| 3 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |

```
Draw: Match ID: 3
Los: Match ID: 6
Win: Match ID: 7
Win: Match ID: 8
```

When I try to inner join wins & losses against the Match table it works but the second I include the draws it does not return anything.

If I try just returning draws it works but then inner joining either losses or wins causes 0 results.

Can anyone help me with the code that'll work?

Query I'm trying:

```
SELECT Matches.ID AS MatchID, Winners.Name
    FROM Matches
            inner JOIN Draws
            ON Matches.ID = Draws.MatchID
            
            inner JOIN Winners
            ON Matches.ID = Winners.MatchID
            
            inner JOIN Losers
            ON Matches.ID = Losers.Match ID
                        
            and (Winners.winner_id_num = 5
            OR
            Losers.type_id_num = 5
            OR
            Draws.IDNum = 5
            
                )
            
            GROUP BY match_id_num;
```

Comment: I added some extra blank lines before the tables that where not correctly show (because of a [bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404376/rendered-view-requires-blank-line-before-tables-but-preview-accepts-both) on SO).

Comment: Can/Will you add the queries that you actually tried ?

Comment: In the result from `wins & losses`, you will not see match number 3.   An inner join will only show values that are in the left table AND in the right table.  You need to solve this using  `LEFT JOIN`s.

Comment: For more reading on this, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28719292/724039

Comment: Added in the query I've been using

Comment: Change all `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` (and read comment above.. )

Comment: Hi, Luuk. I've changed that but it's pulling through other none related matches too

Comment: It is unclear, from your question, what a "none related matche" is.   You can try to [edit] your question and add this info, and maybe even  create a  [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0) to make this problem clear.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use **UNION** between the 3 tables with results and join the output with the `Matches` table.

```
SELECT r.Result, r.IDMatch FROM (
    SELECT *, 'Win' as Result FROM Winners WHERE IDNum = 5
    UNION 
    SELECT *, 'Los' as Result FROM Losers WHERE IDNum = 5
    UNION 
    SELECT *, 'Draw' as Result FROM Draws WHERE IDNum = 5
) AS r
INNER JOIN Matches AS m ON m.ID = r.IDMatch
ORDER BY m.Date DESC
```

The output would be:

```
Draw  3
Los   6
Win   7
Win   8
```